# How to improve my question style (based on a real example)?

Tags: support, questions, specific-question, quality-improvement

There are several (many) questions on Meta staring with "why was my question downvoted?". This is another one, which I ask specifically to learn something about how SO works.

My [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34398178/how-to-call-a-function-on-change) was about JS and jQuery (it does not matter).

I wonder why it was downvoted. I do not expect someone to have telepathic powers, I just would like to understand what is [inherently wrong in such a formulated question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

- would that be the level of the question? It is not that different from others I asked when learning new things.
- would that be the fact that this is a duplicate? I would have never guessed from the title of the duplicate (to my uninformed eye, it is not a duplicate - the answer to the duplicate does answer my question though, and I will mark it as such).

Again, I am looking for generic recommendations: code was there (with a pointer to an online IDE to simplify the tests), I checked for dupes (true, I did not specifically mention that), the docs do mention that the argumeent is a `handler` which could have pointed me towards the answer but, well, I do not have the right reflexes withthe nomenclature.

In short: what could be done to improve the question?

Comment: Nothing wrong about the question. The problem, however, is a groaner, and the javascript folks get lots of groaners.  That's their fault, for using an interpreted language without compile time checking.  So, not only do you get bugs like this, but you also get downvoted.

Answer (score 2):

I find your question to be fairly well formulated. The things I generally look for in a question are as follows:

-A detailed description of the problem
-Things you have tried yourself 
-A detailed description of the erorr (preferably with stacktraces)
-A good description of what you want to accomplish.

When I read your question it contains most of these elements. My guess is that you are getting downvoted because it is a duplicate of an existing question. The problem why this annoys people so hard is that it appears that you were too 'lazy' to look for an answer yourself..

So to conclude I think the problem with your question was that you could have known the answer by searching some more first. Most trivial cases have already been answered here or elsewhere